# What does Python need to install sqlite3 module?

Tags: python, sqlite

Okay,

I kinda asked this question already, but  noticed that i might have not been as clear as i could have been, and might have made some errors myself.

I have also noticed many people having the same or similar problems with sqlite3 in python. So i thought i would ask this as clearly as i could, so it could possibly help others with the same issues aswell.

What does python need to find when compiling, so the module is enabled and working?
(In detail, i mean exact files, not just "sqlite dev-files")?

And if it needs a library, it propably needs to be compiled with the right architecture?

Comment: What other people? What other question? sqlite3 has been part of the standard library since Python 2.5, so I don't know why anyone would have problems with it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I as see he wants to build python from sources. This really requres some extra system preparation.

Comment: He's asking about it from a "I'm compiling my own Python perspective."  When building Python it will auto-magically determine which standard libraries to build, including the bindings for sqlite3.  @gjordis Which version of Python?

Comment: Yes, apparrently I failed to articulate as clearly as i wanted again. Yes I'm compiling python from source and to a ARM platform. All my other modules compile just fine, but sqlite3 has been a problem.

Comment: Have you successfully built sqlite?  That's the place to start.

Comment: Yes for host system. Only static build for target ARM system

Comment: @jszakmeister Didn't notice the question. Python ver = 2.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2291aff20a05/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#l109) of cpython's sqlite module calls various sqlite3 functions and uses sqlite3 structures (similar to class definitions in Python).

Upon compiling the source code (to the `python` binary), the C compiler needs the definitions of those functions (for example so that it can abort if the parameter count doesn't match). For that reason, Python's sqlite module [includes the sqlite3 *header* file `sqlite3.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2291aff20a05/Modules/_sqlite/connection.h#l33) that contain information about the parameters of the `sqlite3_*` functions (but *not* their implementations). [<sub>(More information about header files on Wikipedia)</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file)

Also, when [linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) the python binary, the linker needs to get information about the actual binary representation of the used sqlite3 methods and other objects. This information is in the files that reside in `/usr/lib` and end in `.so`, `.la`, or `.a`. They must be compiled for the *target* architecture (i.e. the architecture of the binary you're trying to create) - most of the time, that's the architecture of the current system.

Comment: Thank you, this was a straight an answer as i could have wanted. Will try to move on with this information. I was on the right track, but i was unclear on all the files needed.

Comment: You can actually see what Python is doing for it's autodetection [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f130ce67387d/setup.py#l984).  It's looking for the header, and the corresponding library in one of a few default search paths.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would like to install python form sources. To make *sqlite* module available you have to install *sqlite* package and its *dev files* (for example *sqlite-devel* for CentOS). That's it. YOu have to re-configure your sources after installing the required packages.

Btw you will face up the same problem with some other modules.

Comment: Umm, the question explicitly states `In detail, i mean exact files, not just "sqlite dev-files"`, and your answer is `sqlite package and its dev files (for example sqlite-devel)`?

Comment: @phihag There is no reason in `sqlite-dev` content listing here. Just run `yum install sqlite-dev` or `apt-get` or whatever else you use for pakacge management and it will install all required files.

Comment: The information i wanted to gain from this was that: What are the files from the devel packet it needs, I dont need the whole listing of the packet, but for example : "It needs the sqlite3.h" file". Installing any packet from a packet manager is out of the question for this case. Building a custom linux from source. (Not completely my project)